# How to show tightness of a Poission$(\lambda)$ family, $\lambda \in \Lambda$ implies $\Lambda$ is bounded.

Tags: probability-theory

I'm still learning how to properly work with the tightness of a sequence. The question is as in the title:

Assume that a family Poisson$(\lambda)$, $\lambda \in \Lambda$ is tight. Show that $\Lambda$ must be bounded.

What I have so far I have from the definition that we must have $\lim_{M \rightarrow \infty}\inf_\lambda\mathbb{P}_\lambda([-M,M]) = 1$. Writing out the definition for the probability measure I have

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}_\lambda([-M,M]) = \mathbb{P}_\lambda([0,M]) &= \sum_{k=0}^M \frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^k}{k!} \\
&= e^{-\lambda}\sum_{k=0}^M \frac{\lambda^k}{k!}
\end{align*}

From here we can see that as $M \rightarrow \infty$ we have that $e^{-\lambda}\sum_{k=0}^M \frac{\lambda^k}{k!} \rightarrow e^{-\lambda}e^\lambda = 1$, but from what I can see this holds for arbitrary values of $\lambda$. What am I missing?

Comment: Don't forget that Poisson distribution is *only* positive for positive numbers, so $\Bbb P_{\lambda}([-M,M]) = \Bbb P_\lambda([0,M])$ and thus there is no second sum.

Comment: Christ, you're right. I'll adjust that.

Comment: Interestingly, the formula that you had is still correct in a way that $(-k)! = \infty$ in the sense of $\Gamma$-function and hence the latter sum is $0$.

Comment: You are missing the fact that **first** you have to take $\inf_\lambda$ and **then** the limit with $M\to\infty$. Otherwise, clearly 
$$
  \lim_{M\to\infty} \Bbb P([-M,M]) = \Bbb P(\Bbb R) = 1
$$
regardless of the shape of the distribution $\Bbb P$. Taking the infimum **before** the limit is crucial.

Comment: Ah, after a little contemplation I got this. Let $M \in \mathbb{N}$, then $\sum_{k=0}^M \frac{\lambda^k}{k!} < e^\lambda$ from the taylor series. So let us assume that $\Lambda$ is unbounded, say $\Lambda = [0,\infty)$. Then $\inf_\lambda \mathbb{P}_\lambda$ doesn't exist as $\lambda' > \lambda$ implies $\mathbb{P}_{\lambda'}([0,M]) < \mathbb{P}_{\lambda}([0,M])$. EDIT: Or more probably $\inf_\lambda \mathbb{P}_\lambda([0,M]) = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

A simple proof is as follows. For every $\lambda\gt0$, $\mathbb P_\lambda([\lambda,+\infty))\gt0$, and, by the central limit theorem, $\mathbb P_\lambda([\lambda,+\infty))\to\frac12$ when $\lambda\to\infty$, hence there exists some positive $c$ such that $\mathbb P_\lambda([\lambda,+\infty))\geqslant 2c$ for every $\lambda\geqslant1$.

Turning things the other way around, this means that if there exists $M\geqslant1$ such that $\inf\limits_{\lambda\in\Lambda}\mathbb P_\lambda([-M,M])\geqslant1-c$, then no $\lambda\geqslant M$ is in $\Lambda$, that is, $\Lambda\subseteq[0,M]$.